# How does Neura know the optimal time to notify the user's?

Tags: android, notifications, push, user-activity, neura

I want to send a push notification to my user to take his pills. I am trying to implement the Neura SDK to understand my user's behavior. Can Neura send a notification to my User to take his pills before he goes to sleep ?

Answer (score 1):

Neura tracks various events, the list you can find here:[Neura Events](https://dev.theneura.com/docs/api/events).

Whenever Neura detects an event, it notifies the application(developer) and sends it via an API call, the application/developer, then decides what to do with that information.